# CORS error on some API endpoints but not others in same controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I have a controller with multiple API endpoints. Most endpoints work as expected but there are 2 which throw a CORS error when deployed on a remote server.

> Access to fetch at 'BACKEND URL' from origin 'FRONTEND URL' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have omitted some code below for brevity.

The API `/api/person/uid/14` works as expected in both localhost and on a remote server.

The API `/person/email/john@email.com` works on localhost, but returns an error when deployed on a remote server.

Both frontend and backend are hosted on the same machine and sit on the same domain. The only difference in the URL are the ports (frontend 3000; backend API 8082).

Having said that, the first API (and many others in this controller) work on both local and the remote server, only the email and mobileNumber validation APIs are throwing a CORS error, which makes this really puzzling.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

**PersonController.java**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PersonController {

@Autowired
PersonService personService;

@GetMapping("/person/uid/{uid}")
public Boolean uidExists(@PathVariable("uid") String uid) {
    return personService.uidInUse(uid);
}


@GetMapping("/person/mobileNumber/{mobileNumber}")
public Boolean mobileNumberExists(@PathVariable("mobileNumber") String mobileNumber) {
    return personService.mobileNumberInUse(mobileNumber);
}

@GetMapping("/person/email/{email}")
public Boolean emailExists(@PathVariable("email") String email) {
    return personService.emailInUse(email);
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY)
@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
public Map<String, String> handleValidationExceptions(
        MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    Map<String, String> errors = new HashMap<>();
    ex.getBindingResult().getAllErrors().forEach((error) -> {
        String fieldName = ((FieldError) error).getField();
        String errorMessage = error.getDefaultMessage();
        errors.put(fieldName, errorMessage);
    });
    return errors;
}
}
```

**PersonService.java**

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

@Autowired
PersonRepository personRepository;

// NOTE: ...NotDeleted and ...InUse methods implies deleted == false

// read methods
public List<PersonDto> findAllNotDeleted() {
    return personRepository.findByDeleted(false).stream()
            .filter(p -> !p.getDeleted())
            .map(Person::toDto)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public Optional<Person> findByIdInUse(Long personId) {
    return personRepository.findByPersonIdAndDeleted(personId, false);
}


// checkers
public Boolean uidInUse(String uid) {
    return personRepository.findByPersonUidAndDeleted(uid, false)
            .isPresent();
}

//edit: check if personid is the same as personname
public Boolean uidInUse(String uid, Long personId) {
    Optional<Person> personOptional = personRepository
            .findByPersonUidAndDeleted(uid, false);
    return personOptional.isPresent() &&
            !Objects.equals(personOptional.get().getPersonId(), personId);
}

public Boolean mobileNumberInUse(String personMobileNumber) {
    return personRepository.findByPersonMobileNumberAndDeleted(personMobileNumber, false)
            .isPresent();
}

public Boolean emailInUse(String email) {
    return personRepository.findByPersonEmail(email).size() > 0;
}

public Boolean idInUse(Long id) {
    return personRepository.findByPersonIdAndDeleted(id, false).isPresent();
}


// create / update methods
public PersonDto createNotDeleted(CreatePersonDto personDto) {
    return personRepository.save(personDto.toPerson(false)).toDto();
}


//for deletion
public PersonDto save(PersonDto personDto, Boolean deleted) {
    return personRepository.save(personDto.toPerson(deleted)).toDto();
}

//normal save
public Person save(Person person) {
    return personRepository.save(person);
}


// helpers (if other controllers need can move to util)
public String generateUid() {
    String randomString;

    do {
        randomString = generateRandomString(8);
    } while (uidInUse(randomString));
    return randomString;
}

private String generateRandomString(int length) {
    int leftLimit = 48; // "0"
    int rightLimit = 122; // "z"
    Random random = new Random();

    return random.ints(leftLimit, rightLimit + 1)
            .filter(i -> i <= 57 || (i >= 65 && i <= 90) || i >= 97)
            // "9" and below OR "A" to "Z" OR "a" and above
            .limit(length)
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
            .toString();

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with consumes/produces, try adding produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON or other media type and adjust your request headers as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response antey, would you mind elaborating please as I don't quite get your suggestion.

Comment: I mean modifying @GetMapping(path="yourPath", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)